# Key derivation scheme with shared secrets?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, key-derivation, secret-sharing

I want to derive a list of sub-keys `derived[t]` from a master key `mk` by a key derivation function `KDF`:

```
derived[t] = KDF(mk, t)
```

However `mk` has already been distributed by a `M`-of-`N` threshold secret sharing scheme:

```
shared_keys = secret_sharing(mk, M, N)
```

Is it possible to find a KDF and a secret sharing scheme such that I can derive a list of keys from the shared secrets like below? Maybe combine a homomorphic KDF and secret sharing scheme?

```
pieces = random_pick(shared_keys, M)
derived2[t] = recover([KDF(s, t) for s in pieces])
assert derived[t] == derived2[t]
```

Comment: I've never heard a homomorphic KDF. What does prevent you from recovering the secret then using KDF?